# Excel ODBC SQL query doesn't bring updated data on Refresh

Tags: sql, excel, join, odbc, refresh

I've created a ODBC query in SQL retrieving data from Other Excel sources and making a JOIN. The query runs fine on the first time, but if I try to update the data source and then Refresh the query, it doesn't generate any erro, but doesn't bring the updated figures either.

This problem started to happen since I've added the LEFT JOIN clause to the query.

Any ideas on how to solve it?

below the query code:

```
SELECT A.Type, B.Product, B.`Active Ingredient`, B.`Category`, A.VPC_Group, Max(A.Portfolio1) as Portfolio1, sum(A.`'Qty1'`) as 'Qty1', sum(A.`'NS1'`) as 'NS1', sum(A.`'GP1'`) as 'GP1', sum(A.`'NSLC1'`) as 'NSLC1', Max(A.Portfolio2) as Portfolio2, sum(A.`'Qty2'`) as 'Qty2', sum(A.`'NS2'`) as 'NS2', sum(A.`'GP2'`) as 'GP2', sum(A.`'NSLC2'`) as 'NSLC2', Max(A.Portfolio3) as Portfolio3, sum(A.`'Qty3'`) as 'Qty3', sum(A.`'NS3'`) as 'NS3', sum(A.`'GP3'`) as 'GP3', sum(A.`'NSLC3'`) as 'NSLC3'
FROM (
SELECT Type, `Code Norm`, VPC_Group, Max(PF1) as Portfolio1, Sum(Qty1) AS 'Qty1', Sum(NS1) AS 'NS1', Sum(GP1) AS 'GP1', Sum(NSLC1) as 'NSLC1', Max(PF2) as Portfolio2, Sum(Qty2) as 'Qty2', Sum(NS2) as 'NS2', Sum(GP2) as 'GP2', Sum(NSLC2) as 'NSLC2', Max(PF3) as Portfolio3, Sum(Qty3) as 'Qty3', Sum(NS3) as 'NS3', Sum(GP3) as 'GP3', Sum(NSLC3) as 'NSLC3'
FROM (
SELECT Type, `Code Norm`, IIF(Type='Indent','Indent', IIF(`Area code` = '500', 'FA', 'w/o FA')) as VPC_Group, null as PF1, 0 as Qty1, 0 as NS1, 0 as GP1, 0 as NSLC1, null as PF2, 0 as Qty2, 0 as NS2, 0 as GP2, 0 as NSLC2, Portfolio as PF3, Qty as Qty3,NS as NS3, `GM PIMS` as GP3, NS_BRL as NSLC3
FROM `C:\Users\mzsampa\Company\Brazil-LDN-Controladoria-INT - Documents\General\Projetos\Modelo_Resultado\Sales\SM_Database - 2023.xlsm`.Tabela Tabela
WHERE (Version = 'RFC 2023 05 V01') AND (Type IN ('Third Party', 'Indent', 'IFRS 15')) AND (`Year` = 2023)
UNION ALL
SELECT Type, `Code Norm`, IIF(Type='Indent','Indent', IIF(`Area code` = '500', 'FA', 'w/o FA')) as VPC_Group, null as PF1, 0 as Qty1, 0 as NS1, 0 as GP1, 0 as NSLC1, Portfolio as PF2, Qty as Qty2, NS as NS2, `GM PIMS`as GP2, NS_BRL as NSLC2, null as PF3, 0 as Qty3, 0 as NS3, 0 as GP3, 0 as NSLC3
FROM `C:\Users\mzsampa\Company\Brazil-LDN-Controladoria-INT - Documents\General\Projetos\Modelo_Resultado\Sales\SM_Database - 2023.xlsm`.Tabela Tabela
WHERE (Version = 'RFC 2023 04 v02') AND (Type IN ('Third Party', 'Indent', 'IFRS 15')) AND (`Year` = 2023)
UNION ALL
SELECT Type, `Code Norm`, IIF(Type='Indent','Indent', IIF(`Area code` = '500', 'FA', 'w/o FA')) as VPC_Group, Portfolio as PF1, Qty as Qty1, NS as NS1, `GM PIMS` as GP1, NS_BRL as NSLC1, null as PF2, 0 as Qty2, 0 as NS2, 0 as GP2, 0 as NSLC2, null as PF3, 0 as Qty3, 0 as NS3, 0 as GP3, 0 as NSLC3
FROM `C:\Users\mzsampa\Company\Brazil-LDN-Controladoria-INT - Documents\General\Projetos\Modelo_Resultado\Sales\SM_Database - 2023.xlsm`.Tabela Tabela
WHERE (Version = 'WP 2023 v11') AND (Type IN ('Third Party', 'Indent', 'IFRS 15')) AND (`Year` = 2023)
)
GROUP BY Type, `Code Norm`, VPC_Group) as A
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT `Extranet Items Name` as Product, `Extranet A#I#Name` as `Active Ingredient`, `Cód_Material`, Category
FROM `C:\Users\mzsampa\Company\Brazil-LDN-Controladoria-INT - Documents\General\Projetos\Modelo_Resultado\DE_PARA_PRODUTOS_REVISADO_V03.XLSM`.de_para_prods) as B
ON (A.`Code Norm` = B.`Cód_Material`)
GROUP BY A.Type, B.Product, B.`Active Ingredient`, B.`Category`, A.VPC_Group
```

I was trying to combine several tables into a single database with a Left Join bring product complementary data from a central table.